# Jackson: sub-class properties hidden by @JsonProperty & @JsonView on super class

Tags: java, json, jackson

Suppose I have two classes:

```
public class Super {
    @JsonView(SpecialCaseView.class)
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "super name";
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Duper extends Super {
    private String name = "John Smith";

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
}
```

When I do a normal serialization of a `Duper` object, (e.g, with `new ObjectMapper().writerWithView(ADifferentView.class).writeValueAsString(new Duper())`), I would expect to get

```
{
  "name": "John Smith"
}
```

Instead, I get nothing. It appears this is because the super class's "name" property is getting picked up first, but then Jackson ignores it because of the specific view.

**Is this a bug?**

If not, is there any way around this, or at least a way to detect it, or get a warning?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, which version of Jackson are you using? Anyway, I just tried this code (with Jackson 1)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Duper());

System.out.println(json);
```

Which results in

```
{"name":"super name"}
```

If you put *@JsonView* on your *getName()* method in the subclass, you will get what you want.

```
@JsonView(SpecialCaseView.class)
public String getName() {
   return name;
}
```

The result

```
{"name":"John Smith"}
```

Comment: Jackson 2.7.3. And I should have clarified - I'm serializing using one of a few different views, and I'd like Duper's "name" to show up in all of them. (ideally without having to create a parent-view...)

Comment: I believe that will work only if your views subclass SpecialCaseView (but you apparently don't want that) .

Comment: Right. Bummer. Thanks.